# Matrix not filling up with 1 where necessary in R

Tags: r

I am trying to fill a matrix with ones (1) where the index corresponds to the max of another matrix of the same dimension.
below is a reproducible example

```
set.seed(1)
matric <- matrix(rnorm(3000), nrow = 500, ncol = 6)

best <- matrix(0, nrow = 500, ncol = 6)
n_end <- 500

for (i in n_end) {
  best[which(matric[i,] == max(matric[i,]))] <- 1
}
## the best model has the higher sum
best1 <- colSums(best)
```

Please Help!! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `seq_len` or `1:n_end` and inside the loop, as we are assigning to the same row of 'best', index that matrix as well

```
for(i in 1:n_end) {
  best[i,][matric[i,] == max(matric[i,])] <- 1
 }
```

---

Or if there is only a single max value per row, then use `max.col` as it is faster and vectorized

```
best[cbind(seq_len(nrow(best)), max.col(matric, 'first'))] <- 1
```

---

Or with `rowMaxs` from `matrixStats`

```
library(matrixStats)
+(matric == rowMaxs(matric))
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Both methods worked perfectly though the vectorized one was faster as usual.